# oracle update billions data from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two big table, table A contains 1.4 billion rows, table B contains 14 million rows. My sql like this: `update A set A.cola=(select colb from B where A.cola=B.cold) where exists (select 1 from B where A.cola=B.cold and colb is not null)` 
`cola`,`cold` are index. table is too large to update in one transaction, But I'm not familiar with PL/SQL, anyone have experience with handle this problem efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Use `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO table_a A
USING ( SELECT A.rowid AS rid, B.colb
          FROM table_a A
               INNER JOIN table_b B ON A.cola = B.cold
         WHERE B.colb IS NOT NULL ) upA
   ON (A.rowid = upA.rid)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.cola = upA.colb;
```

Comment: sorry, updated my question, it's not suitable for `merge` because I need change `on` clause column in table A

Comment: this doesn't sound right :D

Comment: columns referenced in the ON clause cannot be updated.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I mean updating something that you use for joining sounds strange.

Comment: yeah，but this is what I need to do.

Comment: @jie try out the new implementation.